# Is it possible to use eigen 3.3.3 on Windows with __ARM_NEON__ defined?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

When I try to use Eigen 3.3.3 on Windows with __ARM_NEON__ defined, I get the following compilation error (followed by a bunch of similar ones):

```
eigen\src/Core/arch/NEON/PacketMath.h(109): error C2766: explicit specialization; 'Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<Eigen::internal::Packet4f>' has already been defined
```

The code around this error looks like this:

```
template<> struct unpacket_traits<Packet4f> { typedef float   type; enum {size=4, alignment=Aligned16}; typedef Packet4f half; };
template<> struct unpacket_traits<Packet4i> { typedef int32_t type; enum {size=4, alignment=Aligned16}; typedef Packet4i half; };
```

Packet4f and Packet4i are defined (in PacketMath.h) as:

```
typedef float32x4_t Packet4f;
typedef int32x4_t   Packet4i;
```

And float32x4_t and int32x4_t are defined (in MSVC's arm_neon.h) as:

```
typedef __n128   float32x4_t;
typedef __n128   int32x4_t;
```

So the compilation error makes sense, but is this supposed to work somehow with Eigen 3.3.3, or is this a bug? Any suggested workarounds, other than disabling vectorization (via EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE)?

Comment: I'm afraid ARM-NEON with MSVC has never been tested, so it is likely that the preprocessor checks are not correct (and I don't think any of the maintainers runs that combination). You should file a bug-report for that (and ideally figure out how to patch the `NEON/PacketMath.h` header to make it work)

Comment: I created a bug here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1428
If I come up with a suggested fix, I will update the bug.